# Window resize and init run together

Tags: javascript

I know I read something about this somewhere around here, or maybe I'm wrong, but is there a way to say for example call a function, or run a code, both on init and on window resize, from one line?
What I mean, instead of this:

```
if (somecondition){
    console.logo('runs on init');
};
$(window).resize(function(){    
    if (somecondition){
        console.logo('same condition runs on resize');
    };
};)
```

Can be written somehow like this:

```
window(init,resize){
    if (somecondition){
        console.logo('runs both on init and resize');
    };
}
```

Dont know if this is at all possible, or even exists, was asking because it really gets annoying keeping a large chunk of code duplicating it all over the place, on init and on resize.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

best I can think of off the top of my head would be to put all the code you want to execute into a named function, e.g.:

```
function namedFunc() {
  if (somecondition){
    console.logo('runs on init');
  };
}
```

then add two event listeners to the window in one go and pass them both the named function.

```
$(window).on({
  ready: namedFunc,
  resize: namedFunc
});
```

Comment: Yep, thnx, good solution, but I like Connors more, seems a bit more to what I was looking for.

Comment: I edited my solution because I wasn't precisely right, and I think I may have come even closer to your initial request.

Comment: Right on eriese, exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Create a function then... Like this

```
var someAction = function(){
     console.log('runs both on init and resize');
};

if (somecondition) {
    someAction();
}

$(window).resize(someAction);
```

Comment: Yep, this seems to be what I was looking for. Make things a tag easier. Thanks!